# MembershipProvider in .NET for CAS Shibboleth

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, cas, shibboleth

Is it possible to write a MembershipProvider in .NET for CAS Shibboleth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually use a custom MembershipProvider when want to change the data source (es from sql to xml). By implementing a MembershipProvider you can override the Providerbase methods and change, for instance, where the Membership will verify if a user exists or where its stores it.
So the answer is yes you can, there are a few drawbacks though. Membership in Asp.Net is usually part of the application and should run in the same domain, differently from an Authentication mechanism (like OpenId or Shibboleth). This means that you can wrap your [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) around Shibboleth but you could end up with having some methods that are not supported by this provider (the reset password function for instance). Having the data provider for Membership on your side of the app ensure you got full control over it. You can use the Asp.Net membership on your website in order to manage users/roles, login/logouts and integrate Shibboleth as an external authentication service. Try giving a look at how [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) works.

Comment: This is the kind of answer i was looking for. Thank you